# Ordering Wordpress posts by most recently commented on

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

What's the query to list wordpress posts by most recent, with posts most recently commented on going to the top of the order? (Standard "message board" style)

This post looked promising:

[Ordering Wordpress posts by most recent comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698438/ordering-wordpress-posts-by-most-recent-comment)

But the query is clearly wrong.

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you think there's a problem with the answers to that question, I suggest you comment there.

Answer (score 0):

How about;

```
SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts LEFT JOIN $wpdb->comments
ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->comments.comment_post_ID
GROUP BY $wpdb->posts.ID
ORDER BY $wpdb->comments.comment_date DESC
LIMIT X,Y
```

This would get posts, limited in the range X,Y, with posts that have comments, and those with the most recent comments, listed first.

UPDATED

Additonal ORDER BY clause;

```
ORDER BY $wpdb->comments.comment_date DESC, $wpdb->post_date DESC
```

Comment: Interesting but what I'm really looking for is "message board style" - a chronological list of posts, and those with the most recent comments at the top.

Comment: That query should do it, though I forgot to add the secondary ORDER BY clause (check revision).